# Cordova - downloading zip file to application

Tags: android, ios, cordova, zip

I am building a Cordova application for Android, iOS, Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8.
I would like to download a zip file form a server or a cloud service, such as Google Drive, Dropbox or some other.
My version is 3.3.0.
I have tested the Documentation one, but nothing happened. Also, search some other website, but no one work.

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var uri = encodeURI("http://some.server.com/1.zip");
var fileurl= "\assets\www\data\1.zip";



fileTransfer.download(
uri,
fileURL,
function(entry) {
    console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
},
function(error) {
    console.log("download error source " + error.source);
    console.log("download error target " + error.target);
    console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
},
false,
{
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
    }
}
);
```

Please help me what I should change or do. Also, I want to ask if the path is in the iOS ,windows phone and windows 8.

Comment: What errors you are having? Look at the console and see the errors.

Comment: As I am using command line to build the application. I find the application (apk file) in a folder of ant-build and send it to a android phone to test. Nothing output when I open it and the wifi has some transfer after go to that page. I have try to find is there anything has downloaded, but nothing can be found.

Comment: Falling back on PROMPT mode since _cordovaNative is missing. Expected for Android 3.2 and lower only. cordova.js:966 　　　　　　　　　　　　processMessage failed: invalid message: cordova.js:1031

Comment: I got two error message above when using chrome desktop to run the page

Answer (score 0):

1. change var uri to the your server address, for example on localhost
2. var fileurl = encodeURI("cdvfile://localhost/persistent/1.zip");

Answer (score 0):

```
function downloadFile() { 
 var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();var uri = 
 encodeURI("http://yourserver/yourzip.zip");
  var fileURL =  "///storage/emulated/0/localstorage/zipfile.zip";

  fileTransfer.download(
  uri, fileURL, function(entry) {
     console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
  },

  function(error) {
     console.log("download error source " + error.source);
     console.log("download error target " + error.target);
     console.log("download error code" + error.code);
  },

  false, {
     headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
     }
  }
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
downloader.init({ folder: 'DownloadedData', fileSystem: cordova.file.externalDataDirectory,unzip: true});
        downloader.get("path of your server");
        document.addEventListener('DOWNLOADER_downloadSuccess', function (event) {
            var data = event.data;
            alert("successfully downloaded");
        });
```

add the below permissions in config.xml in order to gain access to device Storage

```html
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Internal" />
    <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
    <preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="files,files-external,documents,sdcard,root" />
```

without this permission download wont be successfull